# How do I pass a future to serve_with_shutdown

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, rust-tokio

I am building a server and would like to serve until a [oneshot receiver](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/sync/oneshot/struct.Receiver.html) tell me to stop. For that I am using [tokios serve_with_shutdown](https://docs.rs/tonic/0.1.0/tonic/transport/server/struct.Router.html#method.serve_with_shutdown). My understanding is that the service will run until the future `signal` is ready

```rust
pub async fn serve_with_shutdown<F: Future<Output = ()>>(
    self, 
    addr: SocketAddr, 
    signal: F
) -> Result<(), Error>
```

**How do I pass the oneshot receiver as a signal?**

Passing it directly like `serve_with_shutdown(some_addr, receiver);` gives me `unused implementer of futures::Future that must be used`.

I tried implementing my own future. Same error.

```rust
pub struct OneShotFut {
    receiver: Mutex<tokio::sync::oneshot::Receiver<()>>,
}

impl Future for OneShotFut {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut rec = self.receiver.lock().unwrap();
        if rec.try_recv().is_err() {
            return Poll::Pending;
        }
        Poll::Ready(())
    }
}

//... 

serve_with_shutdown(some_addr, OneShotFut {
                receiver: Mutex::new(receiver),
            })
```

I cannot await the future when passing ti to `serve_with_shutdown`, since that will directly return `()`

Comment: Please include the full compiler error message. Are you sure the `unused implementer of futures::Future` refers to the `Receiver`, and not `serve_with_shutdown` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `serve_with_shutdown` is an `async fn` it returns a `Future` that too must be awaited:

Inside another `async fn`:

```rust
serve_with_shutdown((some_addr, OneShotFut {
    receiver: Mutex::new(receiver),
}).await
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `.await`-ing on the result, you probably don't want to use `OneShotFut`. It is deficient because you never use the `Context` to trigger a wake-up. Using a `oneshot::Receiver` is the way to go, but passing it directly as you tried initially would run into an error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<tokio::sync::oneshot::Receiver<_> as Future>::Output == ()`
   --> src/main.rs:33:10
    |
33  |         .serve_with_shutdown(some_addr, receiver)
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `Result`
    |
    = note: expected unit type `()`
                    found enum `Result<_, tokio::sync::oneshot::error::RecvError>`
```

But to ignore any error from the oneshot receiver, which could happen if the sender is destroyed, you simply need to wrap it in an `async` block like so:

```
Server::builder()
    .add_service(...)
    .serve_with_shutdown(some_addr, async { let _ = receiver.await; })
    .await?;
```